# Is there a simple way to minify Angular 2 quick start app

Tags: angular, typescript, minify

I have spended a lot of time trying to find a way to minify all Javascript generated by TypeScript compiler but i haven't found any way of minifying the Angular 2 Quick start app for production mode:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Is there any way to minify application created with this sample (with systemjs.config.js). Have any one succeeded in minifing it for production ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the build system in this Angular 2 seed package. It's really well done.

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

It can do what you ask, and lots more.